# Excel to CSV is very slow

Tags: excel, performance, csv

We receive multiple Excel files from different partners.  The problem is that these excels are differently formated.  So sometimes we get excels with merged fields or with EAN numbers as E+ numbers.  So we have created a vbscript that loops through the rows and cells and does various checks and adjusts the cells and then writes the line to a csv file.  This works well for small files but for larger files, it takes extremely long.

I have read through a number of posts but could not find a solution

Does anyone have suggestion on how to optimise this?

```vb
OPTION Explicit

Dim Arg
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
'Excel objekte
DIM fso, objxl, objwb, objSheet
'Define Variables for Arguments
DIM src_file_path, dest_file_path, dest_sheet, dest_file_name, SheetNr
'Define Output files 
Dim objFile
'Define working variables
Dim LRow, LCol, zeile, spalte, aktsheet

ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
dest_file_path     = "C:\WORK\"
src_file_path      = "C:\WORK\Test.xlsx"
SheetNr            = 1
SheetNr            = Int(SheetNr)
dest_file_name     = "DS_CSV.csv"

LRow = 0
LRow = CLng(LRow)
LCol = 0
LCol = CLng(LCol)
 
wscript.echo off
Set fso        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objxl      = createobject("excel.application")
set objwb      = objxl.workbooks.open(src_file_path)
set objSheet   = objwb.Worksheets(SheetNr)
objxl.DisplayAlerts = False
dest_sheet = objwb.Sheets(SheetNr).Name

objSheet(dest_sheet).Select
objSheet.Activate

'Delete empty cells
Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4
objwb.Worksheets(dest_sheet).Columns("a:a").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

'Find number of rows and cells
LRow=objxl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LCol=objxl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

If LRow = 0 Then LRow = 1
If LCol = 0 Then LCol = 1

'start formating 
Format_Number LRow, LCol

'close DS_CSV.csv
objFile.close
objFile.quit

'close excel
objxl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objxl.Workbooks.Close
objxl.Application.Quit
Set Arg      = Nothing
Set objwb    = Nothing
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objxl    = Nothing

WScript.quit 99

'----------
sub Format_Number (LRow, LCol)
  ON ERROR RESUME Next  
  dim result, CsvStr, listsep, s_value, vrow
  Zeile = 0
  Zeile = CLng(Zeile)
  spalte = 0
  spalte = CLng(spalte)
  listsep = ";"
    
 'open DS_CSV.csv file
  Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile((dest_file_path+dest_file_name) ,8 , True)  
    
  with objxl.ActiveSheet
        
  For zeile = 1 To LRow   
    CsvStr = ""
    For spalte = 1 To LCol
        s_value = ""
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) = False And Str(.Cells(zeile,spalte).Value) = "Fehler 2029" Then
      s_value = "'" & Mid(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Formula, 2, Len(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Formula))
    end if 
            
    If IsNumeric(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) = False And (InStr(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value, vbLf) <> 0 Or InStr(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value, vbCr) <> 0) Then
      s_value = CStr(Replace(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value, vbLf, " "))
      s_value = CStr(Replace(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value, vbCr, " "))
    end if 

    'Unmerge cells:
    If .Cells(zeile, spalte).MergeCells Then.Cells(zeile, spalte).MergeArea.UnMerge
            
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) = True Then
          If IsDate( .Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) = False Then 
        .Cells(zeile, spalte).Style = "STANDARD"
      'NumberFormat changed to General as certain partners have changed Style:
      If objxl.ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").NumberFormat <> "General" Then
            objxl.ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").NumberFormat = "General"
        s_value = CStr(.Cells(zeile, spalte).value)
      End If
    Else
          'remove E+- formating
      If IsNumeric(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) And Len(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) > 11 And inStr(1,.Cells(zeile, spalte).Text, "E+",0) <> 0 Then
        s_value = CStr(FormatNumber(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value,1,0,0,0))
        s_value = Left(s_value, Len(s_value) - 2)    
      ' If cell value > 11
      ElseIf IsNumeric(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) And Len(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value) > 11 And InStr(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value, ",") <> 0 Then
         s_value = CStr(FormatNumber(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value,20,0,0,0))
      End If
    End If
    if s_value = "" then s_value = CStr(.Cells(zeile, spalte).Value)
          CsvStr = CsvStr & """" & s_value & """" & listsep
      Next 
      objFile.WriteLine(CsvStr)
    Next 
  End With
    
end sub
'---------------`
```

Comment: Your code gives me a syntax error. You have two `Next` keywords at the bottom but only one `For` keyword.

Comment: The code is slow by design, you're running Excel as an out-of-process server.  Lots of overhead every time you access a spreadsheet property.  Notable every access to .Cells(zeile, spalte).Value is a round-trip to the server, easily sped up by accessing it just once and storing it in a variable.  Also a scenario where security software tends to get over-exited.  Get a real speedup by running this as an Excel macro so it runs in-process, avoiding both the process interop overhead and (hopefully) the anti-malware product.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for the suggestion.  We have changed our vbscript to now call a Macro and this works well when we execute it directly, but we receive a "Remote procedure call failed" error when we attempt to execute the script from our ETL tool.  I have saved the vbscript and macro on the same server as the ETL tool runs and also execute the vbscript directly with the ETL user.  This works fine but still no luck executing from the ETL tool.